# Manipulating torch.nonzero

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 3D image coded as a Pytorch tensor of dimensions [dim1, dim2, dim3]. This image is segmented into 100 uniform regions (1 value for all voxels in a region) and I have a list of 100 lists, each sub-list r of which contains the voxels in region r (so there are as many rows as voxels in region r and 3 columns, as this is a 3D image).

What I want to do is: starting from a 3D image and this list of 100 lists, obtain a list of 100 values whose element at index r is the sum of the image values in region r.

I have tried this (list_vox_regions is the famous list of 100 lists):

```
for r in range(len(list_vox_regions):
     for vox in range(list_vox_regions[r].shape[0]):
          values[r] += image[tuple(list_vox_regions[r][vox].tolist())].item()
```

and it seems to work but I am sure there is a much more simple solution as I am a beginner in coding. The thing is that image is Pytorch tensor so I had to use tuple for indexing.

NB : list_vox_regions has been obtained with torch.nonzero.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example by initializing `list_vox_regions` and `values`?